# The difference "do you think so?" and "do you think like that(this)"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I think there seems to be a difference though it'd be very little.

> 1.Do you think so?

In my opinion, it means similar to "is this your way of thinking?"

> 2.Do you think like that(this)?

Somewhat differently, I guess it means similar to "is that(this) like your thought?"

And I want to know how to use them correctly in answer to a question.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, **so** in that usage requires as antecedent an assertion or a set of related assertions.

> He's not answering the phone. He's probably in the shower.
>   --Do you think so? He takes that phone everywhere.

Or

> In the November elections we're going to see college-educated suburban women turn out in large numbers, but also an increased turnout by white males without  college education.
>   -- You think so?

Whereas "like that" can refer to a more general pattern of thought.

> I don't know why she's not answering the phone. Maybe the house burnt down, or she's been kidnapped, or maybe she been in a car accident.
>   --There's no reason to think like that.  Her phone just might be out of power.

Comment: Right: Think like that does to something already discussed, an antecedent, as you show. A minor point: think so is often in relation to a yes or no idea. "He hates candy." "Do you think so?"

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken with non-native English speakers who have used both of those phrases interchangeably.  I would agree with your analysis that they are slightly different.

Colloquially, *do you think so* would be an inquisition to another person's opinion to confirm their belief.

*Do you think like that* is a more cumbersome sentence structure, and less conversational.  I would take it as an implication that the person asking the question was trying to find out if my thoughts follow a certain pattern or methodology, as opposed to simply confirming my opinion.